# Рекурсивная функция, которая выводит случайное не повторяющееся число

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Решил сделать вывод случайного изображения на слайдер и сделать функцию, которая возвращает случайное число. Но что-то она работает не корректно и иногда возвращает повторяющееся число. 
Функция примерно такая:

```js
let imgNameArray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],['entertament/1','entertament/2']];
let maxImagesPush,
    usedIndexForRandom = [];
maxImagesPush = 6;
//Получаем в функцию длинну массива
function randomImage(length){
    let randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * length);
    //Проверяем совпадает ли случайное число с числом которое уже было добавленно
    for(let i=0;i<usedIndexForRandom.length;i++){
        if(randomIndex == usedIndexForRandom[i]) randomImage(length);
    }
    //Добаваляем новое число в массив проверки
    usedIndexForRandom.push(randomIndex);
    return randomIndex;
}
for(let i=0;i<maxImagesPush;i++){
    console.log(randomImage(imgNameArray[0].length));
}
```

Можете подсказать, где может быть ошибка?

Comment: более простой подход - перемешать массив с числами и извлекать их по очереди. вот функция для перемешивания https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/690987

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, можно не перемешивать, а вырезать рандомный элемент, тогда на следующей итерации исходный массив будешь меньше уже и повторно число не выпадет :)

Comment: @Grundy можно и так - зависит от требований.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К чему такие сложности?

```js
const imgNameArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
const maxImagesPush = 6;
for(let i=0;i<maxImagesPush;i++){
    console.log(
    ...imgNameArray.splice(Math.floor(imgNameArray.length*Math.random()), 1)
    );
}
```

Comment: спасибо работает) а не подскажете из за чего криво работал мой вариат?

Comment: @Horchynskyi потому что`if(randomIndex == usedIndexForRandom[i]) randomImage(length);` тут return randomImage забыли.